# How does -net smb=<path> work in Termux without root (no low ports)?

Tags: qemu, samba

I find I can map a host folder to linux client using smbmount in Termux qemu, though it won't work for a Win9x client. Qemu uses the installed Samba, but smbd -D, run independently, always crashes for lack of sockets. Perhaps the sockets are mapped to > 1024 using NAT by qemu. If so, why does WinME refuse to map the network drive? I have tried various smb.conf (qemu smb works without one) settings but I suspect they are ignored or overruled by qemu's smbd. Can anyone save me analysing the sources?